# What is the best ACR (auto content recognition) technology for building a second screen television app with?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, broadcast, image-recognition, television

What is the best ACR (auto content recognition) technology for building a second screen television app with ?

Potential solutions may include: tvsync, tvtak.tv, civolution, and audible magic.

Comment: It's hard to know what you consider "the best" without knowing your individual requirements.  You haven't even specified what platforms you are targeting!  Please clarify your question with as many details as possible.  Please also see the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Civolution primarily provides watermarking technology and Audible Magic provides digital fingerprinting. Watermarking is good for forensics but Fingerprinting is better suited for second screen applications.  TVtak requires you to use the camera on the phone which might be less convenient for users to use. Both Civolution and Audible Magic listen via the microphone.  TVsync is new to the market and is unproven.  Audible Magic has probably been around the longest and owns many patents which gives them a significant advantage.

With watermarks, a barely detectible tone needs to be inserted into the original content during production.  That is not the case with fingerprinting.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above, there is no straight forward answer on "what is the best ACR ?" as it depends on the requirements and what use case you are trying to cover and what content you are trying to deliver. We at [mufin](http://www.mufin.com/usecase/second-screen/) offer a **audio fingerprinting technology** that is very robust and is optimized for mobile applications that do not necessarily require an internet connection. Compared to watermarking, audio fingerprinting does not require a modification of the reference audio signal which is one of the main advantages.

Answer (score 0):

you may check syntec tv (audio fingerprinting solution) for what they offers. It is really efficient and fast recognition which they can provide.